# Is it possible to create an instance by using a scanner?

Tags: java

We know how to create an instance by writing in the main...

```
Class newObject = new Class();
```

Is there a way to create a 'newObject' by user's input something and pops a new newObject? I was thinking using the Scanner but i am not sure how it could be done. I was guessing like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Class sc.next(); = new Class();
```

or like this?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
(some name) = sc.next();
Class (some name) = new Class();
```

So the user inputs an object name (some name) into the scanner and that object name (some name) will be created.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can have a container which maps your user input(String as key) to instantiated object

Comment: The exact way no, but you can come close with Apache commons BeanUtils class... But it's not integrated with the scanner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to make a constructor that takes in a Scanner class to create Class, given that you have access to the Class code and can put in the value.

```
Class testClass{

  testClass(Scanner input)
  {
    //Populate the class.
  }

}
```

If Class is a primitive, then you could just use the nextInt (Or other related) type functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection for your purpose as follows :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
String className = sc.next()
Class userClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);
Object classInstance = userClass.newInstance();
```

The class loader is used as its name states : for loading classes. Just give it the name of the class and if this class is found within your executable libraries (i.e. jar files or classes) or in the project build path it will create the class (still not the instance) you need.

Than you use this class to create an instance which results in a general object with the desired class implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeanUtils in Apache commons to write a method that will do this for you. I have done something like following before.

```
    public <T> T bindBean(String[] line, Class<T> cls) throws Exception {
        T newInstance = cls.newInstance();
        Map<String, Object> properties = BeanUtils.describe(newInstance);
        Field[] format = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {
            properties.put(format[i].getName(), line[i]);
        }
        BeanUtils.populate(newInstance, properties);

        return newInstance;
    }
```

You can create a method like above and then pass the line[] parameter from the Scanner. Or you can get the values from inside the method. Thats just preference.

I have thrown the Exception here because I just want to demonstrate my point and not handle them. Hope this is what you are looking for.